# Jmeter-Radio button response not getting back

Tags: jmeter

The scenario is while checking a radio button an event is posted to server and one more radio button will display after server post back.But the response from radio button click in the view result tree looks like this and radio button is unchecked

```
1|#||4|53|pageRedirect||%2fsitename%2fCommon%2fErrorPages%2fError.aspx|
```

What is the probable cause for this.The page used update panel control in it.And have event validations.which is currently turned off.

```
Sampler Result:
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2016-03-31 11:38:05 IST
Load time: 24
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 24
Size in bytes: 349
Headers size in bytes: 260
Body size in bytes: 89
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2016 06:08:26 GMT
```

HTTPSampleResult fields:

```
ContentType: text/plain; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what's going on.

Try to record a real interaction with a browser (using either the Jmeter proxy or some other recorder like Httpfox or Httpwatch), and compare the recorded transaction with the Jmeter one.

Also double check Cookie Manager, and eventually XSRF tokens.

Comment: While clicking on radio button an async postback is happening.The page used update panel control in asp.net,which is now commented for performance testing.After recording the same ,post request have async post=true and script manager have some value.Also event validation is turned off.Still its shown while recording.

Comment: Http request Parameters are given below.
__ASYNCPOST=true
__EVENTTARGET=ctl00$MainContent$dlReportType$ctl01$rdbtnReportType
__EVENTVALIDATION=${EventValidation}
__VIEWSTATE=${Viewstate}
ctl00$MainContent$ScriptManager1=ctl00$MainContent$upnlReportType|ctl00$MainContent$dlReportType$ctl01$rdbtnReportType
ctl00$MainContent$dlReportType$ctl01$rdbtnReportType=rdbtnReportType
ctl00$MainContent$hdnItemID=${ItemID}
ctl00$MainContent$hdnItemTypeID=1

Comment: These parameter are very typical with .NET application, nothing new here.   Beside Cookie manager and XSRF, you must tick the "encoding" flag for each posted parameter. You can find here a good reference: https://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter